# getPackageName() on a null object refrence

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, fragment

There is an error which comes sometimes when I open an activity form a fragment 
since I know from API 23 it should have been getContext so for that sake I also implemented try catch on my code like this

```
authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) {
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Home_page.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Home_page.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
```

but also it gives sometimes error of null pointer object reference on Context.getPackageName() what could be the probable reason???

Comment: Where are you calling this code block . Add whole class .

Comment: i have put this code on firebase auth state listener

Comment: authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null) {

Comment: Can you post the whole class ?

Comment: ok i will post the whole class

Comment: Activity is Context. You can use `getActivity`. Ignore the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listeners for AsyncCall can be trigger in any state of the calling entity . So you should first check for existence of entity in this case for `Context` or `isAdded()`. Below is an example .

```
 authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Home_page.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what excatly is Async call sir??

Comment: A call that's invoked asynchronously. You registered the `authStateListener`, user left the activity, you didn't unregister the listener, the listener is called and `getActivity` returns null. Boom!

Comment: Firebase provides methods to add and remove listeners. To remove a listener you have pass the same instances you had added . Look into documentation .